# built in functions of python. how to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def cleanTileAtPosition(self, pos):       
     x = math.floor(pos.getX())
     y = math.floor(pos.getY())
     self.tiles[(x, y)] = True

def getRandomPosition(self):

     return Position(random.random() * self.width,
                     random.random() * self.height)
```

My questions:

1. In the first function what is `pos`?  `pos` is not a part of any class or dictionary. How can we get the `x` and `y` from it?
2. In second function, is `Position` a built-in function of python? If that is, why do we multiply `width` and `random.random`? What sense does it make? Also, is `pos` used in first function an object of this `position`? help me out.

Comment: The full code this comes from seems to be available [here](http://assets.openstudy.com/updates/attachments/4fd2fee3e4b057e7d221f7a8-chribonn-1339228071101-ps11.py). As you learn about classes and instances (see Martijn Pieters' answer) it might be worth reading the full code to understand what's happening. `Position` is a class defined at the beginning and `pos` is an instance of `Position` passed to the function `cleanTileAtPosition` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Both functions are part of a class definition (the `self` is a hint).

Neither `pos` nor `Position` are python built-ins. They must've come from a custom library or were defined earlier in the same source file. Perhaps these methods are actually *part* of the `Position` class definition itself.

Most likely, `pos` is expected to be an instance of class `Position`.

I suggest you start with reading the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before you continue; work your way through it at least until the section on classes and instances (chapter 9).